# using datepickerplus in ext js

Tags: extjs, datepicker

i have been playing around with the ext js library for showing multi month calendar

**http://www.lubber.de/extjs/datepickerplus/**

one issue is in all the examples are either coming off of another control(combo, textbox) or inside a window object

does anyone know if there are any examples of simply displaying the calendars on a regular page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the source of http://www.lubber.de/extjs/datepickerplus/ around line 635 where the `dWin` object is being instantiated you should get an idea on how to add it to a page.

Basically this script (be warned, it has loads of commented code and actually is quite a mess) creates an Ext Window, with several items of which one has a datepickerplus xtype.

It should be possible to also render the datepicker to another dom element directly but i think that this extension to Ext doesn't support this out of the box so you should probably extend the object and override the render method.

Hope that helps